# Security patches for LG K8 Android 6.0

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, security, lg

Recently I looked at my Android security patch level (after hearing about the BlueBorne vulnerability) and saw that is is at 2016-07-01, 14 months old.

My device details:
LG K8 4G dual (LG-K350nds), 
Android 6.0 (not rooted)

How do I get the latest security patch. Online resources say I should go Settings > General > About phone > Common > Update Center > Software Update > Check now for update, but it says “You are using the latest software version for current OS”.
Is my device not supported? I bought it last september, so two months after the latest security patch I got.

Edit: I just received an update, security patch level now at 2017-09-01. Though this isn't the latest, it fixed BlueBorne, and it's nice to see finally getting patches from LG.

Comment: I have same model on same patch. I'll have to disappoint you because you will not receive patch for blue born vulnerability, or any other (I'm sure there is at least one more lethal bug unpached), at least not officially, maybe we can somehow create patch and make to stay stock rom. However soon I will try to make LOS ROM but I don't know what will happen since K8 have troubles when even TWRP is flashed. However if I succed I don't know if the bug will be patched because maybe it has to be pushed by OEM (like in broadcom bug case).

Answer (score 0):

Today I received update on my K350nds and now it is on 2017-09-01 security patch level, and according to [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.armis.blueborne_detector) it is not vulnerable anymore, also this should include dirty cow exploit fix, didn't check that one.